# Combine many scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I would like to combine two different scopes in my model. I have this:

**Post_model**

```
scope :with_tasks, -> { where(cat: 3).includes(:user).includes(task: :users) }
scope :with_events, -> { where(cat: 4).includes(:user).includes(event: :users) }
scope :with_comments, -> {where(comented: true).includes(comments: :user)}
```

**Post_controller**

```
def index 
  @posts = current_user.posts.with_tasks + current_user.posts.with_events
end
```

But I think it is not a really elegant way to achieve it, and I cannot include the comments scope.

Do you know a method to join this scopes into a new one (like the example below)?

```
scope :with_elements, -> { self.with_tasks.merge(self.with_events) }
```

What would allow me to call this method into my `post#index`:

```
@posts = current_user.posts.with_elements
```

Comment: Have you tried just chaining them, like so `current_user.posts.with_tasks.with_events` ?

Comment: The problem is that is two different kind of cat, so I need to merge them

Comment: Why are you hardcording `where(cat: 3)` into your scopes?

Comment: Another code smell is `where(comented: true)` - don't use a boolean column for this. Use a count on the association or a `LEFT INNER JOIN` which precludes rows without a match in the join table. `joins(:comments)` will give you an inner join.

Comment: Use https://github.com/rails/arel.

Answer (score 0):

```
TASKS = 3
EVENTS = 4
scope :with_tasks_and_or_events, ->(cat) { 
  cond = {}.tap do |c|
    c.merge!(task: :users) if cat.include? TASKS
    c.merge!(event: :users) if cat.include? EVENTS
  end

  where(cat: cat).includes(:user).includes(**cond)
}
```

And use it like:

```
with_tasks_and_or_events([TASKS])
with_tasks_and_or_events([TASKS, EVENTS])
```

Or, better, use [Relational Algebra](https://github.com/rails/arel).

Or, even better, revise your database structure.